# Codeigniter CSRF problem: CSRF request and response token mismatch

Tags: codeigniter, csrf, csrf-protection

I spend a lot of time searching for the solution for this problem, but with no luck so I am hoping somebody can help me.

I enabled CSRF protection and set csrf_regenerate to true (I want to regenerate the CSRF token on each request).

I am testing with my login form. The problem occurs when first submit the form with invalid data and the refresh the page (F5). I get thew error: The action you have requested is not allowed, so the CSRF token validation failed.

I noticed that when submitting the form with invalid data, CSRF request and response tokens do not match and I thing that is the cause of the problem.

I am guessing I'm not the first one with this problem, so I really hope somebody can help me out.

I you need any additional data please let me know.

Thanks and regards, Gregor

Comment: As you mentioned in the above comment you have set the csrf_regenerate to TRUE, so you got the mismatch token.Please read this article https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html .

Server consider the new request when you refresh the page, so codeigniter update the token.

Also when you inserted the invalid data one request cycle is completed by the server.

Comment: youd have to fetch and populate the csrf field before the next request as the csrf token wouldn't be valid anymore. there really isn't an easy fix, even with ajax you'll have same issue.

Comment: @Alex I had the same issue with AJAX, but I already solved it. How do I fetch the csrf cookie and populate the field before the next request? I tried but as far I can see I can only fetch the csrf response cookie, but not the csrf request cookie

Comment: post relevant code please, namely the form + controller

Comment: @Alex Here is the form: https://codepad.co/snippet/OO9aIGVT. Here is the controller: https://codepad.co/snippet/RXWrK9BX. Hope this helps

Comment: i don't see any issues. if you refresh the page the token should regenerate as you aren't using ajax to submit do you see the hidden csrf field change on refresh? maybe trying printing the csrf token from security class on same page to see if it matches. dont really know what to tell you :(